# How to add a marker in a specific point in a seaborn lineplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm plotting a simple lineplot with seaborn and I'd like to add a marker in two specific points of the lineplot.

I checked the documentation, and I know that matplotlib has some markers support (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/markers_api.html), but I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

I have something like this:

```
sns.lineplot(x="time", y="cost",
                   data=df_time)
```

I'd want to specify the plot to have a marker at both the rows n1 and n2. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The show a marker of the first and second point of a line plot use the [`markevery` argument](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/markevery_demo.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,3,4,6,7,9]
y = [3,2,3,1,3,2]

plt.plot(x,y, marker="s", ms=12, markevery=[0,1])

plt.show()
```

[image]